# How can we configure Stylus for absolute paths in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, stylus, absolute-path

My Angular app is configured to use [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) for its styling. Almost all my components' styles inherit from `src/styles/common.styl` which provides configuration and mixins. However that means my stylus files all have long relative trails:

```css
@import '../../../../styles/common';
```

This also means that when we set up a new component, we have to add this line then figure out the appropriate number of `../`'s to add based on its folder nestling level.

I'd like to be able to use absolute paths for our Stylus code instead. That means being bale to use an import like the following from any component in the application regardless of folder nesting level:

```css
@import '/styles/common';
```

**What's the best practice for achieving absolute paths for Stylus imports in Angular 7?**

It looks like [this is theoretical possible](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2281) by configuring stylus-loader, but I can't find a clean way to do that for Angular. [Custom webpack configs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack#custom-webpack-config-object) seem like a relevant option, but they appear to be used for wholesale replacing the default config rather than just amending it with a piece of configuration, and I would prefer not to have to redo the webpack configuration from the ground up to just configure a Stylus setting if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stylus you can do root relative style imports pretty easy with ~:

```
@import "~src/styles/common";
```

where the baseUrl in the root tsconfig.json is:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
```

With a different baseUrl you'll need a different import pattern. For example a baseUrl of `src/` requires you to use `@import "~styles/common"` for the path to still resolve to `src/styles/common`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually works in Stylus! I've updated your answer with the correct Stylus syntax for this scenario.

Comment: I'll be able to award the bounty tomorrow, so it'll be yours then.

Comment: glad i could help